# How do order statuses/states work in Magento 1.4.x

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, status

As far as I understand Magento have various order ***statuses*** under global/sales/order/statuses which can be altered by either copying app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml to local scope or overriding it with your custom module.

There are also global/sales/order/states defined in the same file and as far as I understand ***states*** are something like ***statuses*** groups. Only ***states*** (not statuses) can be set at the order status in magento and ***statuses*** are something like ***states*** subdivisions. So in administrator interface you can change ***statuses*** of a placed order but you can't change ***state*** from the order status drop-down (you can change it by either invoicing the client or canceling the order).

As far as I understand you can easily add a new ***status*** to your Magento but can't add new ***state*** as ***states*** are somehow hardcoded with the rest or Magento order processing logic. I really hope that I'm wrong.

Please correct me if I'm wrong in any point as these are just my thoughts and it might be quite far from real Magento 1.4.x flow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm quite sure that 'state' is free data, it can be set to ANY value using the setData option on an order instance. So if you write a custom module that can load an order, set data to one of your new 'states' and test with what ever custom logic you require.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(1);
$order->setData('state','myCustomState');
$order->setData('status','onCustomState');
echo $order->getState()
// Returns myCustomState
```

its worth bearing in mine that CLOSED/CANCELLED are protected states, so trying to use $order->setState('my_state') will fail on those order, but shouldn't fail on setData so you can overwrite a closed or cancelled order with this method.

if you were to overwrite the order model with a custom one you could add your own logic such as isOnCustomState() and allow the order to be handled in any way just by loading by id.

To add 'custom logic' to your order you could do something copy app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php into your local folder, then you can add functions into that model,

```
public function isActive(){ if($this->getState() == 'active'){ return true; } else { return false; }
public function isInActive(){ if($this->getState() == 'deactivated'){ return true; } else { return false; }

public function activate(){
    if(!$this->isActive()){
        $this->setData('state','active');
        $this->setData('status','Active Subscription');

        // some custom code to start a recuring payment

        return $this;
    }
}

public function deactiveate(){
    if(!$this->isInActive()){
        $this->setData('state','deactivated');
        $this->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true,'Your subscription has been deactivated.');

        // some custom code to stop a recuring payment

        return $this;
    }
}
```

now you can load an order and set activate or deactivate on that order to fire your custom code,

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(1)->activate();
```

this code is all untested and just an example of somethings you could try, please don't just dump this code in your model and expect it to work perfectly. in code\core\Mage\Sales\etc\config.xml in the nodes sales/order/states add

```
<activated translate="label">
   <label>Active Subscription</label>
   <statuses>
      <pending default="1"/>
   </statuses>
   <visible_on_front/>
</activated>
```

Comment: In this case why adding another state through XML doesn't work?

Comment: you should just be able to add 'states' into the config.xml for magentos 'sales' module but it wont do anything as states need an action not just to set a flag, this is why you'll need to add custom logic. as in if your custom states is 'active' you'll need to add logic on what to do if an 'active' order is 'cancelled' (e.g. send a notification to paypal to stop a recurring payment.)

Comment: Can you please give any kind of hint how the logic for custom state can be added?

Comment: So I do not have to add anything to XML? $this->setData('state','active'); is adding new state that will be displayed in the orders table instead of processing/pending payment/etc ?

Comment: Yer, that will set the data of the order, you only need to add the xml if you want to be able to call the states on some of the system config pages, but you shouldn't need to do that. Though if i were making a module to add this extra state and its functions I would also add the sates xml aswell. Thanks. Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Magento Order is a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Therefore when you define status it would automatically try to define its state. Altering state directly is not recommended.

When you define status it checks various flags for shipment and invoices and depending in all those it would get the right state. Once order is in approved state however you can easily change status regardless of if there is invoice or any flag etc.